# Word for when someone tips/tilts their head from side to side in lighthearted disagreement

Tags: single-word-requests

Basically what the title says. Just a piece of body language I see, but I have no idea if there's a word for it. It's often accompanied by a merging of someone saying "yes" and "no" at the same time. When they wag their head from side to side, it's almost like their using body language as a metaphor for their brain weighing the two arguments/stances up against each other.

Answer (score 2):

How do you like this one?

**cock**

> to turn, tip, or tilt usually to one side

*cock one's head*

[Merriam-Webster]

Comment: This would work if the head stays in the tilted position.